# How to find the size of a scrollbar slider?

Tags: java, slider, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I'm writing a program that compares two images. Each image is displayed in a jLabel inside a jScrollPane. I want to let the user click & drag on the image to move the image inside the jScrollPane and when the user moves an image the other one moves as well. The problem is when I have two images of different sizes because they move with the same increment and don't reach the end at the same time. I'm trying to find the slider's size to make them move properly and reach the end at the same time.

```
jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
jScrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new HorizontalScrollBarMoved());
jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new VerticalScrollBarMoved());


class HorizontalScrollBarMoved implements AdjustmentListener{
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent ae){

            jScrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
            jScrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
            jScrollPane3.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
        }
    }

class VerticalScrollBarMoved implements AdjustmentListener{
        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent ae){

            jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
            jScrollPane2.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
            jScrollPane3.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(ae.getValue());
        }
    }


private void imageLabel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

        int horizontalScrollBarInitialValue, verticalScrollBarInitialValue;
        horizontalScrollBarInitialValue = ScrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
        verticalScrollBarInitialValue = jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();

        jScrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(horizontalScrollBarInitialValue - (evt.getX() - mousePressedX)/30);
        jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(verticalScrollBarInitialValue - (evt.getY() - mousePressedY)/30);           
    }
```

`mousePressedX` is the variable where I stored the X coordinate where I first pressed the mouse to drag the image.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can find the slider size. It's tunned up automatically. You should rather find the size of `JScrollPage` and compare it to the size of your visible `View`.

Comment: I noticed that the size of the image displayed inside the jScrollPane is the sum of the slider's size and the remaining space in the scrollBar. I actually need to find the size of the remaining space in the scrollbar and the only way I could think of was to first find the size of the slider.

Comment: Why not to find the top of the image and compare to JScrollPane#getHeight, or left of the image and JScrollPage#getWidth?

Comment: For example I have an image with the width of 1024 and JScrollPage#getWidth returns 420, but if I move the slider to the end of the scrollBar the value by which the image moved is 610. So the slider size is 1024-610 = 414. I don't know how to use JScrollPage#getWidth to solve my problem because the sizes are so different.

Comment: You should just setWidth/setHeight of JScrollPane exactly to the image size. Then scroller will work properly. JScrollPane will be smaller (e.g. 420 in height). But will scroll properly?

Comment: If I setWidth/setHeight of JScrollPane exactly to the image size then the jScrollPane will occupy all of the screen.

Comment: I don't see where you set initial width/height from your code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38033/discussion-between-seby598-and-archer)